# Can you set phonegap navigator.notification.beep() to have 2 different beeping sound

Tags: cordova, notifications, beep

i'm trying to build an app with phone gap, I need 2 different beeping sound, but i don't see phonegap has that setting.

Is there ways to change the beeping to a different one? so I can have 2 different beeping sound?

Answer (score 1):

There is JS library to generate audio on the fly:

- http://codebase.es/riffwave/ (I would recommend this lib)
- http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre/
- http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS

Comment: I recommend [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS), but I may be biased because I work on it.  It does not generate sounds for you though.